# Bash script to unzip a file -- get error: Cannot Find or Open

Tags: bash, zip

Here is my script:

```
Z=/var/pixel/sftp/gisftp/pixel_images/pixel_images_archive.zip
if [ $Z ]; then
    echo "$Z exists"
    unzip $Z -d test
else
   echo "$Z doesn't exist!"
fi
```

I get back this when running the script:

```
/var/pixel/sftp/gisftp/pixel_images/pixel_images_archive.zip exists
unzip:  cannot find or open
/var/pixel/sftp/gisftp/pixel_images/pixel_images_archive.zip, /var/pixel/sftp/gisftp/pixel_images/pixel_images_archive.zip.zip or /var/pixel/sftp/gisftp/pixel_images/pixel_images_archive.zip.ZIP.
```

How does it exist, but not exist??

How should I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[ $Z ]` only tests that the string is not empty (and `[ -n "$Z" ]` would have been preferable), not that the file named by the string exists. Use `[ -e "$Z" ]` for that. See the manual page for [`test`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/test.1posix.html) or the documentation of your shell (because `[` may be a shell built-in).

`test` (which is the full name of `[`) also allows you to check whether a file exists and is not empty (`test -s "$Z"`), or if it exists and is a regular file (`test -f "$Z"`) etc.

Comment: [ -e "$Z" ] worked, it turned out the path was wrong, thank you!

Comment: Perhaps even -r as a test, since unzip will want to read it.